# TSQL Query: Escaping Special Characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to escape special characters in a TSQL query. I have done this before:

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

And it has worked. Now I have tried to do this now:

```
UPDATE match SET rule_name='31' ESCAPE '\'
```

But it has failed. I know none of the vlaues have a `\` but it should still work. I am guessing its because it needs a LIKE statement but how else can I escape characters that I am adding to a database?

In addition, does anyone have a link to all the special characters that should be escaped, I couldn't find any documentation on this!

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) clause has a list of characters that require escaping.

`ESCAPE` is only defined as part of the `LIKE` clause, which is why your second query fails (no `LIKE` clause).

Comment: I guessed as much, I'll just have to use the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the ESCAPE clause on the [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) statement is to allow you to treat special characters like '%' as literals.  When your updating there are no special characters that need to be escaped like that.

### Edit

I misunderstood and thought the OP wanted to escape the like special characters.
To escape the `'` you enter `''`.

Comment: So you can update an existing string with one that has single quotes in it? `'`. You have to escape invalid characters or your query won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about the like specific things (%, [], _).  You have to put two single quotes in a row.